# Whether every noun needs one article to describe one person

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

**He was an exceptional planner, an amazing teacher and friend**

Well, I have little doubts about the articles in this sentence.It has articles before two of the nouns and the third is left out. Doesn't seem right.

**He was an exceptional planner, an amazing teacher and a friend**

or

**He was an exceptional planner,amazing teacher and friend.**

When we say *The manager and the CEO* we mean two people and to mean one person we write *The manager and CEO.*

In this case, we're meaning one person so should not it be just one article, just one **a**  or  **an** ? What would be the correct sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence actually means *" ... and an amazing friend"*, so it groups the concepts (teacher and friend) together.
That way, it needs only one *"an amazing"*.

Comment: As a planner he was exceptional, as a teacher and friend he was amazing.

Comment: @Peter Yes. Not that it will help the OP, who hasn't been seen for years...